# React Navigation component conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-router

I have a navigation component in my React app and I want the left and right buttons to go to different pages depending on which page I'm on.
In this example I'm on the page /2, therefore left button goes to /1 and right to /3.

```
class Navigation extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <Navbar className="nav" expand="md">
      <Nav navbar>
        <div className="m-auto">
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink to="/1" tag={RouterNavLink}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleLeft} />
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink to="/3" tag={RouterNavLink}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleRight} />
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
        </div>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar>
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Is there a way I can write for example if statements to change the Navlink to="" property?

For example when I'm on page /3, the left one goes to /2 and right one to /4, etc.

I'm not completely sure this is the right approach at all, so any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use back tick and write a dynamic link as you like for that you have to save the current id in state:

```
<NavItem>
        <NavLink to=`/${this.state.currentId-1}` tag={RouterNavLink}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleLeft} />
        </NavLink>
      </NavItem>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <NavItem>
        <NavLink to=`/${this.state.currentId+1}` tag={RouterNavLink}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleRight} />
        </NavLink>
      </NavItem>
```

But you have to put extra check when the id dosnt exist